# How to keep the numerical pad keyboard visible across navigation controller transitions?

Tags: ios, swift

I have three screens where on each I have a textfield.
I am transitioning between them inside a navigation controller. Text fields have been made first responders.

How can I keep the keyboard visible while the push/pop transitions happen?

Answer (score 0):

Make your every textfield `firstResponder` in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` of every `viewcontroller` something like,

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

so everytime your textfield will show keyboard when your `viewcontroller` will come to front (i mean when your `viewWillAppear` will get called)!